No module named 'confluent_kafka.cimpl' error while updating aws lambda runtime from python 3.9 to 3.11
I want to update my python runtime for aws lambda from 3.9 to 3.11.
Till now, I am using python-3.9 runtime and I have not specified any requirements or additional libraries to my lambda function, still from confluent-kafka import Consumer works fine for my code.
While running on python 3.9 runtime,

The version of confluent-kafka, was using 1.9.2, when I tried to print it.

Now when I am trying to switch the runtime to 3.11, it throws the error..
Unexpected error occurred in lambda: No module named 'confluent_kafka.cimpl'
Question:

Why am I facing this issue, and how can I solve this.
Is there any way of doing this without adding new layer or zip file, please let know here.

Thank you

Hello, Yogesh. Can you share more details on lambda function, Like Either it is Container image or simple Lambda image. Because When, I execute in my lambda environment:  while running in 3.9 Python runtime, it still give me import error.  As confluent-kafka, is not pre installed package I am sure, you will need to add layer to use this package.  But, I am still confuse how it successfully execute in python 3.9 and throwing error in 3.11.

Hey, My bad.. There was a layer attached to that lambda. I think someone removed it. Thank you

Does this answer your question? AWS Lambda Layer import Tuya Connector
